# Undefined variable error in theme option after updating WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress

I have built a theme.. I have hooked register_setting with option name "abc_options"
Now i have updated the theme and my theme consist of two new fields in the theme option panel

```
<input id="welcome_post_char" type="text" name="abc_options[welcome_post_char]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($settings['welcome_post_char'],'abc'); ?>">
```

But when i install this theme with old abc_options in my database table, gives an error

```
Undefined index: welcome_post_char in D:\wamp\www\wptest2\wp-content\themes\presite\inc\admin-panel\theme-options.php on line 394
```

If i do

```
<input id="welcome_post_char" type="text" name="abc_options[welcome_post_char]" value="<?php if (isset($settings['welcome_post_char'])){echo esc_attr($settings['welcome_post_char'],'abc')}; ?>">
```

it doesn't give errors.. But i didn't see this approach in other Themes.. So can anyone please suggest me what is the best approach